# Is there a way to automatically label topics after clustering?

Tags: label, word2vec, topic-modeling

After clustering sentences using K-means and word2vec, I wonder if there is a way to automatically label the clusters.

Comment: What do you mean by labels? If saying "words similar to: Monday, Tuesday" is enough for you, you can find words that are closest to the centroid. If you want labels like "days of the week", it would be much more difficult and you probably cannot avoid using lexical resources like WordNet.

Comment: If you would have been able to do that..why would you need to cluster in the first place?